# How to pattern-match a nested class in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've tried the code below (the equal method is written after [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) book)

```
class Person() {
    class Room(r: Int, c: Int) {
        val row = r
        val col = c

        override def hashCode: Int =
            41 * (
                41 + row.hashCode
            ) + col.hashCode

        override def equals(other: Any) =
            other match {
                case that: Room =>
                   (that canEqual this) &&
                   this.row == that.row &&
                   this.col == that.col
               case _ => false
            }

        def canEqual(other: Any) =
            other.isInstanceOf[Room]
    }

    val room = new Room(2,1)
}

val p1 = new Person()
val p2 = new Person()

println(p1.room == p2.room)
>>> false
```

After some analysing I found that Scala redefines the class `Room` for each instance of `Person` and that's the reason the two rooms aren't equal.

One possibility to resolve the problem is to put the class outside of the class `Person`, but this isn't always what's easiest. (For example if the class has to access some parameters of `Person`.)

What alternatives are there to write the equal method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that your two rooms are instances of a path-dependent type: their types are `p1.Room` and `p2.Room`:

```
scala> :type p1.room
p1.Room
```

One way to make this work is to refer to `Room` using type selection, i.e. as `Person#Room`.

```
class Person() {
    class Room(r: Int, c: Int) {
        val row = r
        val col = c

        override def hashCode: Int = // omitted for brevity

        override def equals(other: Any) =
            other match {
                case that: Person#Room =>
                   (that canEqual this) &&
                   this.row == that.row &&
                   this.col == that.col
               case _ => false
            }

        def canEqual(other: Any) =
            other.isInstanceOf[Person#Room]
    }

    val room: Room = new Room(2,1)
}

val p1 = new Person()
val p2 = new Person()

scala> p1.room == p2.room
res1: Boolean = true
```